# For every 7 elements from Array1, add an element from Array2

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

**What I want to achieve:** Trying to format Array3 as follows:

- 7 Elements from Array1
- 1 Element from Array2
- If no more elements in Array1 or less than 7 elements left in Array1, add the rest of Array2

**Current Code:**

```js
let Array1 = ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Pasta', 'Eggs', 'Juice', 'Coffee', 'Water', 'Nuggets', 'Chicken', 'Sandwich']

let Array2 = ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4']

let Array3 = []
```

**What I attempted doing:**

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < Array1.length || i < Array2.length; i++) {
  if (Array1.length > 0) {
    Array3.push(Array1[i]);
    x++;
    if (x === 7) {
      Array3.push(Array2[y]);
      y++;
      x = 0;
    }
  } else if (Array2.length > 0) {
    Array3.concat(Array2);
  };
};
```

**Facing issue:**

Even though the above sort of works I still face these issues:

1. I feel as if it's clunky and could be of higher performance.
2. I obviously want to display Array3 to the user because it's ordered but lets take this example where I progressed in the array and removed the first few arrays:

```js
let Array1 = ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8'. '9'. '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'];

let Array2 = ['a'];

let Array3 = ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8'. '9'. '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'];
```

Array3 is displayed, but what if I add `b` to `Array2`? if I run it by the code above it'll re-order the elements to show `a` after '10' because it's the 7th element but I don't want it to do so, I want prior set values to stay the same but new ones to be ordered. similarly I want the `b` to be after `14` because it's the next multiplier of **7** but it's not the 14th element. So it's kinda messed up

**My approach:**

I'm thinking of making the elements objects that have the following:

```js
{
 item: string,
 position: number
}
```

Whenenver a new item is added to the loop it's added with (Array3.length + 1) but I'll have a check for the remainder of 7 and skip all the multipliers of 7, if an item is from `Array2` I add them strictly to the next free multiplier of 7.

Please advise me if I should go on with my approach or if there is an easier way of handling it. Please note that for the simplicty and length of the question I didn't add the actual array elements, the elements are similar to:

```js
{
 user: {name: string, id: string}
 requeue: boolean
 position: number
}
```

Comment: please add sample inputs and outputs

Comment: you are talking about number of elements (7 from array 1 and 1 from array 2) but then you want also to check that an element is a multiple of 7. I am confused.

Comment: @QZAK I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate until the index for slicing is greater or equal to the length of both arrays and add later the rest of both to the result set.

```js
function merge(a, b, sizeA, sizeB) {
    const result = [];
    
    let i = 0, j = 0;
    
    while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
        result.push(...a.slice(i, i += sizeA), ...b.slice(j, j+= sizeB));
    }
    
    result.push(...a.slice(i), ...b.slice(j));
    
    return result;
}

const
    array1 = ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Pasta', 'Eggs', 'Juice', 'Coffee', 'Water', 'Nuggets', 'Chicken', 'Sandwich'],
    array2 = ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4']

console.log(merge(array1, array2, 7, 1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the below code snippet as per my understanding based on the 3 use case you provided at the top in the post. Let me know if any further changes you required.

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Input array1
let Array1 = ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Pasta', 'Eggs'];

// Input array 2
let Array2 = ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4'];

// Result array 3
let Array3 = [];

/**
 * mergeArray() is used to merge two arrays and will return newArray.
 */
function mergeArray(arr1, arr2) {
  // Here we are checking if arrays contains array1 & array2 length and based on that creating newArray.
    if (arr1.length === 7 && arr2.length === 1) {
    Array3 = [...arr1, arr2];
  } else if (arr1.length < 7 && arr2.length) {
    const arr = [ ...arr1, ...arr2];
    Array3 = (arr.length === 7) ? arr : [ ...arr1, ...arr2].slice(0, 7);
  }
  return Array3;
};

// Result
console.log(mergeArray(Array1, Array2));
```